# How can I convert an asterisk delimited text string to HTML using JSP?

Tags: html, jsp

I am working for a client who currently has their product attributes defined in a single textarea field in their CMS. The attributes are separated by asterisks (*)

**e.g.  * 100% cotton * Machine washable * Loose fit**

I want to format these as an unordered list in html but WITHOUT the use of javascript or jQuery. They need to be rendered at JSP page load level.

Unfortunately, amendments to the CMS at this point are not possible for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This looks like something that could be achieved easily with `.replace()`

Comment: Of course. Thanks. This has worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alvaro, I used the following:

```
<c:set var="attribute" value="${product.attributes.value}"/>
<c:set var="attributeList" value="${fn:replace(attribute,'*', '<li>')}" />

<ul>
${attributeList}
</ul>
```